# Re-creating Hello World Contextual Gadget for Gmail not so simple after all

Tags: gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Can someone please assist. I have been wasting so many hours with the **Gmail Contextual Gadget**. I am trying to recreate the [Contextual Gadget - Hello World Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#hello_world_example_code).

I've made the necessary changes to the `manifest.xml` and `gadget.xml`. I am however, struggling with `manifest.json` file.

I have created the following `manifest.json` file which just results in the app redirecting to my site.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Welcome to helloworld example",
  "version": "0.0.0.5",
  "description": "hello world test",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/128.png",
    "16": "icons/16.png"
  },
  "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "app" : {
    "launch" : {
      "url" : "http://www.XXXXXXX.co.za/gadget.xml"
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know, it isn't possible to create gadget by manifest any more.

Try to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/sbrudz/gadget-hello-world

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks so much decided to go the chrome extension route eventually. check out the extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-real-email-signature/mbjaipikpaoofdlmnhhmngmciglljacl